# How to restrict duplicate excel file upload?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a file upload functionality. On upload click, I am inserting the excel data directly into sql table. My sql table doesn't have any unique column.

So whenever the same file uploaded multiple times, the records are duplicating.

How to restrict this duplicate excel file upload?

Comment: The uploaded file has always the same name? Or it is a different name every time you load it? Do you load it many times in a day or just one time a day?

Comment: Create a unique constraint, or avoid multiple uploads.

Comment: Uploaded file name can be anything which the user uploads. We will load it many times a day.

Comment: You could try to extract  a checksum of the uploaded file and verify it against a table where you store all the files uploaded and their checksum

Answer (score 1):

Either you can have a unique constraint/make an autoincrement primary key column to avoid duplicates. Moreover, you can also have a date column if you want your records to be inserted once per each date etc.

If you are doing your load via some command then you can run a post command after the load so as to rename the file or move the file once the loads done